# How to include view in different parts of a website in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to display the info of a database in different parts of my website. I've search in google and Chat GPT about how to make it possible and the answer looks like to create what it's called a partial view. The process is to create a view, after that is to call that view from the controller and finally to @include() that view in the section where you want to display in.

So I've created the view ofertasEmpleo.blade.php in the root of the views folder.
This is the contentof the view.

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Puesto ID</th>
                <th>Empresa ID</th>
                <th>Vacantes</th>
                <th>Fecha Publicación</th>
                <th>Fecha Expiración</th>
                <th>Descripción</th>
                <th>Requisitos</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($ofertas_empleo as $oferta)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$oferta ->puesto_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$oferta ->empresa_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$oferta ->numpuestos}}</td>
                    <td>{{$oferta ->fecha_publicacion}}</td>
                    <td>{{$oferta ->fecha_cierre}}</td>
                    <td>{{$oferta ->descripcion}}</td>
                    <td>{{$oferta ->requisitos}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I've created a function in the controller OfertaEmpleoController

```
class OfertaEmpleoController extends Controller
{

     public function mostrar_ofertas()
    {
        $ofertas_empleo = OfertaEmpleo::all();
        return view(
            "ofertasEmpleo",
            [
                "ofertas_empleo" => $ofertas_empleo
            ]
        );
    }
```

This is the route in web.php

```
Route::resource("ofertas_empleo", OfertaEmpleoController::class);
Route::get("ofertas_empleo", [OfertaEmpleoController::class, "mostrar_ofertas"]);
```

I've include the index of the folder profile --> in index.blade.php

```
<p>Mostrar ofertas empleo para ofertas</p>

      @include('ofertasEmpleo')
```

However it doesn't work. It says **Undefined variable $ofertas_empleo**

```
I've tried something called yield() at the view ofertasEmpleo.blade.php -->
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Puesto ID</th>
                <th>Empresa ID</th>
                <th>Vacantes</th>
                <th>Fecha Publicación</th>
                <th>Fecha Expiración</th>
                <th>Descripción</th>
                <th>Requisitos</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($ofertas_empleo as $oferta)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$oferta ->puesto_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$oferta ->empresa_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$oferta ->numpuestos}}</td>
                    <td>{{$oferta ->fecha_publicacion}}</td>
                    <td>{{$oferta ->fecha_cierre}}</td>
                    <td>{{$oferta ->descripcion}}</td>
                    <td>{{$oferta ->requisitos}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    @yield('ofertas')
```

And the to@export in the index.blade.php of profile folder but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hello to share data through your app, the kind of View you were adviced are View Composers i think: [Laravel View Composers Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/views#view-composers)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with the route definition. The `Route::resource("ofertas_empleo", OfertaEmpleoController::class);` line will cause the `Route::get("ofertas_empleo", [OfertaEmpleoController::class, "mostrar_ofertas"]);` to never get used. And since your controller implements none of the functions that a route resource expects, you will get strange behavior.

I would suggest just removing the line `Route::resource("ofertas_empleo", OfertaEmpleoController::class);`.

For more info on the ins and outs of resource routes, have a look at [the docs for resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: Okey, thank you. I'll see what you've said